# Change the Text value when action happens on the other button SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have 3 swfitui views and they share the common data between each other.I am presenting 3rd view from 2nd view, 3rd view will have list of items when selection of any of the item I am dismissing the listView(3rd) and trying to update the selected item on the 2nd view's(button title). Tried with @state and @binding approach seems value is updating immediately until I do some action on other things.

Passing Value from 1st View

```
@State var initialValue: String?

.sheet(isPresented: $shouldAnimate){
                    SecondView(initialValue: $initialValue)
      }
```

Passing Value from 2nd View

```
@Binding var initialValue: String?

Text(initialValue)

Button(action: {showSheet.toggle()
  ThirdView(initialValue: $initialValue)
  })
```

3rd view

```
@Binding var initialValue: String?

                List(items, id: \.self) { i in
                    Button(
                        i, action: {
                            initialValue = i
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                        
                    )
                }
```

Text should change the value on 2nd `Text(initialValue)`  view once after selection of the item from 3rd, Kindly let me know if you require more information pointing out

Comment: Really difficult to tell what's going on here without a [mre]

Comment: Please provide full code of your views. Especially initializers

Comment: Your code seems fine so I think the problem is in your initializers. I suppose you pass the bindings incorrectly

Comment: Note, you should not have `ThirdView(initialValue: $initialValue)` inside your Button action. Or is the code you are showing not really the code you are using.